# dkms hangs when installing kernel

Tags: kernel, 15.04, dkms

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04. I want to use MPTCP, for which I have downloaded and compiled the modified kernel (https://github.com/multipath-tcp/mptcp, branch mptcp_v0.90). I need at least kernel 3.18 for displayport passthrough. After installing modules and headers, I get to the following line while installing the kernel

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
```

and then it stops. After removing the ">&2" from the dkms-script I get the following output:

```
hp@hp-desktop:~/git/mptcp$ sudo make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.18.19+ arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
  System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 3.18.19+                                                                                                                                                     
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch buildfix_kernel_3.18.patch...patching file nv-drm.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 131 with fuzz 1 (offset 3 lines).


Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.18.19+ -k module KERNDIR=/lib/modules/3.18.19+ IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/3.18.19+/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd; make -C uvm module KERNEL_UNAME=3.18.19+ KBUILD_EXTMOD=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-346/346.59/build/uvm................................................................................
```

The dots keep getting more, but the process is not finished even after hours.

Edit:
After letting it sit for a few Hours it did halt and gave me this Error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.18.19+ (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-346/346.59/build/make.log for more information. [ OK ]
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.18.19+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.18.19+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.19+
Generating grub configuration file ...
...
```

Here is the end of the (extremely long) make.log: http://pastebin.com/QrcqaEEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

Nvidia proprietary driver does not build for this custom kernel. You have options:

1. Use a standard kernel with mptcp patch.
2. Use this kernel and uninstall Nvidia drivers.
3. Fix the build issue in Nvidia module or the kernel.

I am afraid that further questions regarding "how to do one of those" is at the edge of off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you.
I just switched to nouveau to install the kernel and then downloaded the newest driver from the nvidia homepage ("additional drivers" tool did not work) and now it works.